# Need VBA Code for Deselect all slicer items

Tags: excel, vba

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_xxxxx").ClearManualFilter
```

I need to deselect all slicer items.
I tried this

```
For i = 1 To numberOfItems
On Error Resume Next
.SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
Next i
```

Please help

Answer (score 6):

```
Public Sub unselectAllBut(slicerName As String, newSelection As String)
ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName).SlicerItems(newSelection).Selected = True
Dim slc As SlicerItem
For Each slc In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slicerName).SlicerItems
    If Not slc.Caption = newSelection Then
        slc.Selected = False
    End If
Next slc
End Sub
```

Try this! :)

Ex: 
unselectAllBut(UrSlicerName, Item's caption u want to select)